# Use different character encoding for different languages in mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n

I am currently working on a multi-lingual site which has now added Chinese language support on top of the original Japanese and English languages. Unfortunately we have been using `charset: 'ISO-2022-JP` until now which means that many Chinese characters will render as question marks in the emails sent to users. The ideal solution there is to use `UTF-8`, although this has some issues with Japanese characters unfortunately.

I have this code already that I am using to send emails tied to the user language:

```
def set_language
  language_mapping = {
    0 => "ja",
    1 => "en",
    2 => "zh"
  }
  used_language = @reservation.user.language
  I18n.locale = language_mapping[used_language]
end
```

Is there any way to add some kind of conditional for the charset to be connected to this? At present, my mailer helpers have `charset: 'ISO-2022-JP'` but I want to use UTF-8 for any users in the Chinese ('zh') or English ('en') groups. An easy way would be to just manually add the charset each time but that doesn't seem to be the most "DRY" approach.

EDIT for clarity: The line `charset: 'ISO-2022-JP'` is in the default settings at the top.

Apologies in advance if this is a really stupid question, but I cannot seem to figure it out at all.

Comment: The languages can be selected dynamically by users? or it depends from db field?

Comment: It is based on a column `language` in the database that is set when they sign up (EG: sign up from the Japanese site => Japanese language emails)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a pretty simple solution in the end. App default is UTF-8, so I just added this to any mailer which needed ISO-2022-JP as well:

```
charset: (@reservation.user.language == 0 ? 'ISO-2022-JP' : 'UTF8'),
```